# How to insert 2-d list?

Tags: python

Here is my source code I'm doing this without using import math

```
#2-d list append
n=int(input('enter final value'))
l=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    l[i]=[]
    if i==0:
        for x in range(0,n+1):
            if x%2==0:
                l[i].append(x)
    if i==1:
        for x in range(0,n+1):
            if x%2!=0:
                l[i].append(x)
    if i==2:
        for x in range(0,n+1) and x!=1:
            f=0
            a=int(n/2)
            for j in range(2,a):
                if x%j==0:
                    f+=1
            if(f==0):
                l[i].append(x)
     l.append(l[i])
 print(l)
```

it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/New/Desktop/py/2_D.py", line 5, in <module>
    l[i]=[]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I'd like to know how should I correct my code to be able to insert a 2-d list

Comment: can you elaborate, what you are trying to accomplish, as it will be easy for us to help.

Comment: `l` is empty. You then try to assign an empty list to the first element of `l`, but it doesn't have a first element. You probably want to `append` it.

Answer (score 1):

`l` is an empty list. You then try to assign an empty list to the first element of `l`, but it doesn't have a first element as it is empty. You probably want to `append` it instead using `l.append([])`.

Note, in the line:

```
for x in range(0,n+1) and x!=1:
```

The condition needs to go into an `if` statement on the next line and the code block after it indented appropriately.

```
n=int(input('enter final value'))
l=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    l.append([])   # append an empty list
    if i==0:
        for x in range(0,n+1):
            if x%2==0:
                l[i].append(x)
    if i==1:
        for x in range(0,n+1):
            if x%2!=0:
                l[i].append(x)
    if i==2:
        for x in range(0,n+1):
            if x!=1:   # Moved the if statement to a new line
                f=0
                a=int(n/2)
                for j in range(2,a):
                    if x%j==0:
                        f+=1
                if(f==0):
                    l[i].append(x)
    l.append(l[i])
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

write this line :

```
l.append([])
```

instead

```
l[i] =[]
```

when you write l[i] interpreter try to access l[0] but length of l is zero.